# Android 10 don`t connect to WPA wifi programmatically

Tags: android, wifi

For programmatically connection to WPA wifi I`am try to use below code.

```
WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder();
                        builder.setSsid(deviceSSID);
                        builder.setWpa2Passphrase(devicePass);
                        builder.setIsEnhancedOpen(false);


                        WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = builder.build();

                        NetworkRequest.Builder networkRequestBuilder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
                        networkRequestBuilder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
                        networkRequestBuilder.setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier);

                        NetworkRequest networkRequest = networkRequestBuilder.build();
                        final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) StartActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                        ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback;
                        networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {

                                super.onAvailable(network);
                                cm.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
                                                                }
                        };
                        cm.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback);
```

For android versions < 10 i use wifiManager which has reconnection method deprecated. Why does my code not working for Android 10?